# Reverse Lookup JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, combobox

I have been exhaustively searching for the past few weeks for a `Java Swing` `Autocomplete` implementation that allows reverse look up. Here's what I am looking for.

Say that I have a list of people {"Jon", "Billy", "Joel", "Ryan"}. I would like to be able to lookup any username that contains the string "y", and the combobox will then be narrowed down to only the results {"Billy", "Ryan"}. Likewise, if I press backspace then the combobox will be repopulated with the previous matches. Again, another example. If I were to search "Jo", the combobox should be narrowed down to {"Jon", "Joel"}. Now if I press backspace to return the search to an empty string, then the combobox should be repopulated with the original contents {"Jon", "Billy", "Joel", "Ryan"}.

I have taken a pretty deep look into SwingX labs Autocomplete implementation, but it is not providing this functionality. I have tried hacking into the code, but I can't get anywhere of use. Does anyone have any knowledge as to where I could find a library that provides this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the QuickFilter Demo within [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/). They have so many different widgets you are bound to find what you are looking for. You can run their webstart demo. The API cost money but it is loaded with tons of features. I've been using it for over 9 years now.

They also support open source projects. Here is a snippet from their website:

> Free License for Open Source Project
>
> JIDE Software has always been supportive of not-for-profit open source
>   projects. Open source project developers can obtain free single
>   developer licenses, allowing them to use JIDE products in their
>   projects. Please contact sales department with the following
>   information to apply for a free license.
>
> Open source project name Project web site Which JIDE products you wish
>   to use
>
> The free single developer license is exactly the same as the purchased
>   single developer license, except for the following conditions.
>
> You agree to have a link to our web site on your web site and
>   acknowledge the use of JIDE products after successfully integrating
>   JIDE into your project. This license is tied to the open source
>   project you applied for in your email. You cannot use this developer
>   license in any other projects including other open source projects. If
>   you have any other open source projects, please apply for another free
>   developer license. If you plan to use in a commercial project, please
>   consider purchasing single developer license.